# URL Scheme / Deeplink testing from terminal Android

Tags: android, url-scheme, deep-linking

I would like to know how to test some deeplinks for my app. The functionality is already implemented in my app and it works just fine. They way I've been testing it so far was to create my HTML page and assign the URL Schemes to the buttons. I know for a fact that there's a way to test those from Terminal but I forgot what was the command / where should i call it from. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use url scheme in a more efficient way, you can do it inside adb with this following command line:

```
adb shell 'am start "intent:#Intent;scheme=yourscheme://yoururl?param1=value1;end"'
```

Or you can even do it with QrCodes:
Go to [ZXing](https://zxing.appspot.com/generator/) and generate a url of this format:

```
yourscheme://yoururl?param1=value1
```

Then scan it with a QrCode app like [BarcodeScanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can send deeplink request by this command. You can try it now

```
Command Formula  :
adb shell am start -d {your-deep-link}

Example :
adb shell am start -d rmagazine://opensetting/v1
```